# Vector triple product

Tags: vector-analysis

As we know, the scalar triple product represents the volume of parallelepiped.  So similarly what is the physical interpretation of vector triple product?  Can anybody help me?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) discussion provides no physical interpretation of the product, but mentions it's useful.

Comment: It gives the real simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, which is important in physics.